# Trying to get blacs working on 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I get the following when trying

```
sudo apt install blacs-mpi-test
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'scalapack-mpi-test' instead of 'blacs-mpi-test'
scalapack-mpi-test is already the newest version (2.1.0-2build1).
```

But unfortunately the routines in blacs are still missing.

Comment: Please consider `libblacs-mpi-dev`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libblacs-mpi-dev ...... Ref. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=blacs

Comment: Thanks Knud! I added these libraries/paths and got it working, -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread -lblas -lscalapack-openmpi